# Numbered register doesn't record most deleted text within a line?

Tags: register

I am using gVim and it seems the deleted text within 1 line (except `d` following some operations, like `(`) doesn't go to `"1` then shift the `"1-"9` registers, it only goes to `"-`, one example is `diw` command. I didn't see this in the help (`:h registers`), is this expected behavior?

Comment: It *is* in the recent help: "Numbered register 1 contains the text deleted by the most recent delete or change command, *unless the command* specified another register *or the text is less than one line (the small delete register is used then)*.  An exception is made for the delete operator with these movement commands: |%|, |(|, |)|, |`|,"

Comment: I'm curious if you have the same text in your vim version (as I don't know if it's a recent addition).

Comment: @VanLaser The help is the same, my previous understanding is incorrect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is. To quote from [`:h quote_number`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_number):

> Numbered register 1 contains the text deleted by the most recent delete or
> change command, *unless* the command specified another register or *the text is
> less than one line (the small delete register is used then)*. An exception is
> made for the delete operator with these movement commands: |%|, |(|, |)|, |`|,
> |/|, |?|, |n|, |N|, |{| and |}|. Register "1 is always used then (this is Vi
> compatible).

(emphasis mine)

To briefly see the content of your registers after a `"` (or `<C-r>` in insert mode), you can try [vim-peekaboo](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-peekaboo)—it makes selecting the desired register much easier.

Comment: If you don't want to install a plugin like vim-peekaboo, you can also use the builtin-command `:reg` instead. The difference is that the registers are grouped in vim-peekaboo, open in a horizontal split (instead of vertical split), open without you entering a separate command and overall look visually more appealing.