# What is the rationale behind not using the numbered registers for small deletes/yanks?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

This is related to this previous question: [Numbered register doesn't record most deleted text within a line?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4532/numbered-register-doesnt-record-most-deleted-text-within-a-line)

I want to know the rationale for this. I was writing an email and deleted a note in parenthesis (`da(`), then deleted the extraneous whitespace character with `x`. When I looked at my registers with `reg`, the text in parenthesis was not there.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question, asking if it's possible to work around this behaviour](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/).

Comment: Check out the [black hole register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993851/how-to-delete-not-cut-in-vim). My current vim setup has:
`noremap x "_x` With this I can delete a line/selection/whatever then clean up with `x` using visual select. Then paste the original deletion. This provides an excellent place to trash unneeded code and will keep from filling the numbered registers up.

Comment: makes the feature pretty useless IMO which is annoying when 'delete' also means 'cut'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rational is to avoid the deletes to be shifted out of the numbered registers too soon. Typically, if you intent to re-insert deleted text after a while, you put it into a named register you can remember. If you believe you will not need this piece of text anymore, you don't specify a register.

But if you are like me, every once in a while you will regret having deleted some text. If it has been just a few words, the fastest solution is to re-type it. But if it has been a whole paragraph or a code block, I'm happy to find it in `"1` to `"9` somewhere. And I wouldn't want it to be kicked out of `"9` meanwhile by a couple of deleted single-words.

And why one line, not something like "40 characters" which may be a border when it starts to hurt to lose text? Because you don't count characters. If you are doing deletions inside a line, you are aware: This will soon be gone forever.

In your case you may still undo all changes until your delete, yank it and redo everything. There you have your deletion back.